# How to fix "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in SerializeObject IN newtonsoft.json.net

Tags: json.net

I want to serialize the result of query in data table

```
public static IList<DTO.Customer> GetData()
{
    using (DBDataContext odb = new DBDataContext())
    {
        return ConvertDALtoDTO(odb.Customers.ToList());
    }
}

public static List<DTO.Customer> ConvertDALtoDTO(List<DAL.Customer> d)
{            
    try
    {
        string SerializedObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d,Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
        List<DTO.Customer> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DTO.Customer>>(SerializedObj);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But i encountering an "out of Memory" error and after executing the Code the system memory is full and the error below is displayed
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: How many customers does the database have and how much RAM is in your computer?

Comment: at first I'm sorry for the weak English.90 Customer and 8GB RAM. but When Customers Count is more then 10 then memory going full.

Comment: You should run your code in debug mode. This will help you to find exact line at which error happens.

Comment: I've been programming for some time to use the debugger. See the topic is exact serialization of a table that has relation to several other tables that make the operation more heavy during serialization.